# Using a table function with no importing parameters in a HANA graphical calculation view

Tags: hana, table-functions, hana-studio

I'm wondering if someone can help me decipher this Hana Studio Error. I'm very new to this, so apologies if this is just me being simple.

I'm trying to use table functions, just something simple for starters (i.e no params in, table out).

The table:
[image]
[image]

The function:
[image]

The Calc view: (type dimension)
[image]

The error (on activation of the dimension calc view):
[image]

The function itself seems to be fine, i.e. it returns data when I call it from SQL:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the "Web based Development Workbench" or the "WebIDE" for this modelling. If I remember correctly, the HANA studio does not support table functions as data source quite well.

Answer (score -1):

We are using a scripted procedure in Calc view. This works fine for us.

[image: Scripted procedures]